# NSTask and arguments when running command line tools

Tags: cocoa, nstask

How would I pass arguments (host in this case) to NSTask in this code? It does not accept the host `NSString`. If I pass the host value with the ping, for e.g..

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c",@"ping -c 5 www.google.com",nil]
```

then it works. But it won't take the host argument separately. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
task =  [[NSTask alloc] init];
[pipe release];
pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
[task setStandardInput: [NSPipe pipe]];  

[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];

NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c",@"ping -c 5",host,nil];

[task setArguments:args];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
NSFileHandle *fh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stringWithFormat` method of `NSString` class

```
 task =  [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [pipe release];
        pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
        [task setStandardInput: [NSPipe pipe]];  

    [task setLaunchPath:@"path"];

    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c",[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@ %@",@"ping",@"-c",@"5",host],nil];

    [task setArguments:args];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];
    NSFileHandle *fh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are not correct. First of all, you should set the launchpath to /bin/ping, or wherever the task is located, then the arguments should be an **array** of the arguments you would normally enter on the command line, but then seperated by spaces there..

Please take a look at this tutorial [Wrapping UNIX commands](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000025.php) for more information on how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *args = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", @"\"ping -c 5", host, @"\"",nil]
[task setArguments:args];
```

Bash -c needs to take your command in quotes.